# Script to print into Tkinter GUI instead of Eclipse Console

Tags: python, tkinter, pydev

I am a **very** novice programmer interested in python and tkinter.

I have read some tutorials on making basic Tk GUI-based programs.
I am trying to adapt a "tk template" program into a basic ping utility, for fun/learning. My IDE is eclipse with PyDev and my environment is gnome3/ubuntu13.10

Here is my script as it is:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

#import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import pyping
#import multiprocessing

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.lbl = Label(frame, text="Hello World!\n")
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.button = Button(frame, text="Quit",bg="red", fg="white", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Issue PING", command=self.do_ping)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def do_ping(self):
        pyping.ping.func_defaults = (1000, 10, 55)
        h = pyping.ping('g.co')
        for i in h.output:
            print i

#    def draw_console(self):

root = Tk()

root.title("title bar text")
root.geometry("200x100")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When i click the "Issue Ping" button

[image: basic ping program]
.

it prints this to the eclipse debug console (as expected):

```
pydev debugger: starting

PYTHON-PING g.co (74.125.229.168): 55 data bytes
241 bytes from g.co (74.125.229.163): icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=94.4 ms
241 bytes from g.co (74.125.229.165): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=88.7 ms
241 bytes from g.co (74.125.229.162): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=89.9 ms
241 bytes from g.co (74.125.229.161): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=87.9 ms
241 bytes from g.co (74.125.229.160): icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=89.0 ms
241 bytes from g.co (74.125.229.169): icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=89.8 ms
241 bytes from g.co (74.125.229.167): icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=87.9 ms
241 bytes from g.co (74.125.229.166): icmp_seq=7 ttl=52 time=88.6 ms
241 bytes from g.co (74.125.229.164): icmp_seq=8 ttl=52 time=87.2 ms
241 bytes from g.co (74.125.229.174): icmp_seq=9 ttl=52 time=88.9 ms

----g.co PYTHON PING Statistics----
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip (ms)  min/avg/max = 87.188/89.226/94.367
```

.

My goal is to be able to see console output in a "text field" inside the tk gui.

How would go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add a text widget, though that's not the only solution.

Once you've added the text widget, replace the print statement with this:

```
self.text_widget.insert("end", i + "\n")
```

Note that the output won't appear until one of two things happens:

1. the loop finishes, returning control back over to the event loop
2. you call `self.update_idletasks` during each iteration of the loop, which gives the event loop a chance to process redraw events.

Comment: This worked  beautifully, much thanks! Now i just have to figure out how to prevent the gui from freezing while it waits for a response from pyping... I wonder if i can find a multiprocessing tutorial suitable for a novice of my calibre.